# Recommendation Engine with Solr

Tags: solr

When a user searches, I need to also show `You may like these` or  `Other users searched for` or `People also ask` - basically a recommendation engine. We are using `Sitecore 9.1`, `Solr 7.7`.
Does `Solr` have any out-of-box `recommendation engine` functionality?

Comment: Are you looking for Auto suggest? If yes, check these links: https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/2019/11/12/sitecore-api-native-support-for-solr-suggest/ and https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/using-solr-auto-suggest.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually looking for related searches made by other users. For example, If I searched for Televison, I want to also show: Other users searched for: BluRay player, projectors, projector screens etc.
Is there an out-of-box implementation available to use/extend?

Comment: Does this SO answer be of use to you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53042107/10329199?